# Calling a MVC controller function with parameters in a Razor dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I want to call a function with 2 int parameters from an MVC Controller class in it's appropriate Razor view, when selecting something from a dropdown. Basically the dropdown selects the Id of a color(colorId), and the Razor view alreadt knows the Id of a car(carId). These are the variables I need as a parameter.

```
public void GetCarImageBasedOnColor(int carId, int colorId)
        {
            CarImage image = (from c in _context.CarImage
                              where c.CarId == carId && c.ColorId == colorId
                              select new CarImage
                              {
                                  Image = c.Image
                              }).FirstOrDefault();
            configCar.CurrentCarColorImage = image.Image;
        }
```

This is the method from the Controller class, where confogCar is declared globally, and it is the Model on which the Controller and the View are based on.
What I am looking for is calling this method so that the property **CurrentCarColorImage** can be changed based on the 2 Id's.

This is the Razor view code.

```
@if (Model.car.Image != null)
{
    <div class="mt-4">
        <center><img src="@("~/Images/"+@Model.CurrentCarColorImage)" id="carImage" asp-append-version="true" style="padding-top:50px; padding-bottom:40px; width:65%; height:65%" /></center>
    </div>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="@Model.CarImg.ColorId" class="control-label">Color</label>
        <select id="colorDropdown" onchange="GetCarImageBasedOnColor(@Model.car.Id, @Model.CarImg.ColorId)" asp-for="@Model.CarImg.ColorId" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.Colors">
            <option value="">Please select a color</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use ajax to get new CurrentCarColorImage from action,here is a demo:

view:

```
@if (Model.car.Image != null)
{
    <div class="mt-4">
        <center><img src="@("~/Images/"+@Model.CurrentCarColorImage)" id="carImage" asp-append-version="true" style="padding-top:50px; padding-bottom:40px; width:65%; height:65%" /></center>
    </div>
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="@Model.CarImg.ColorId" class="control-label">Color</label>
        <select id="colorDropdown" onchange="GetCarImageBasedOnColor()" asp-for="@Model.CarImg.ColorId" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.Colors">
            <option value="">Please select a color</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        function GetCarImageBasedOnColor() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "GetCarImageBasedOnColor",
                data: { carId: @Model.car.Id, colorId: $("#colorDropdown").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    var newSrc = $("#carImage").attr("src").split("Images")[0] + "Images/" + data;
                    $("#carImage").attr("src", newSrc);
                }

            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

action:

```
public JsonResult GetCarImageBasedOnColor(int carId, int colorId)
        {
            CarImage image = (from c in _context.CarImage
                              where c.CarId == carId && c.ColorId == colorId
                              select new CarImage
                              {
                                  Image = c.Image
                              }).FirstOrDefault();
            return new JsonResult(image.Image);
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this, but in the browser debugger, I get this error every time I pick a color from the dropdown list: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). :44302/GetCarImageBasedOnColor?carId=4&colorId=6:1

Comment: It seems like the compiler doesn't know the path to that function.

Comment: I got it sorted out eventually. In the url the path was not complete : url: "/ConfiguredCar/GetCarImageBasedOnColor".

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons this source might not work is that the select tag requires a list of data that you used from FirstOrDefault.

What I did is as follows :

First, create a method in your service like this to get a car image based on color :

```
 public List<SelectListItem> GetCarImageBasedOnColor(int carId, int colorId)
    {
        return _context.CarImage.Where(c=>c.CarId == carId && c.ColorId == colorId).Select(g => new CarImage()
        {
            Text = g.Image,
            Value = g.id.ToString()
        }).ToList();
    }
```

In Razor source :

```
public void OnGet(int carId , int colorId)
    {
        var groups= GetCarImageBasedOnColor(carId ,colorId);
        ViewData["Groups"] = new SelectList(groups, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

Now in html :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label asp-for="@Model.CarImg.ColorId" class="control-label">Color</label>
    <select asp-for="@Model.CarImg.ColorId" asp-items="@(ViewData["Groups"] as SelectList)">
        <option value="">Please select a color</option>
    </select>
</div>
```